# Resistor or DC-DC converter?

Tags: resistors, dc-dc-converter, fan

I have 19.5VDC input voltage and a 12V fan to be operated. Should I use a resistor connected in series to adjust the voltage on the fan or a step-down DC-DC converter?
The latter might be overkill but I'm concerned about the heat production of the resistor.
Also, which method would be more efficient?

Comment: If you are worried about heat production in the resistor then asking about efficiency should be plainly obvious.

Comment: The DC-DC converter will be more efficient and dissipate less power.  Ho much current does your fan want? If its low enough the resistor may be an OK solution if not then go DC-DC.

Comment: Unless the fan takes a very small current (which I do not expect from a fan) then the DCDC converter will be more efficient. Do some calculations and convince yourself what is more efficient.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. It is a CPU fan so doesn't pull a lot current. I don't know exactly, I will have to measure it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Work out the power dissipation from the current. A typical small fan might draw 0.25A, and so the resistor will need to dissipate 0.25 * 7.5 = 1.875 Watts. Using a 5W resistor, it will stay cool enough to not burn you...

A switching DC-DC converter is an option, but a bit overkill.

A convenient solution is to use a linear voltage regulator such as an LM341-12, which can guarantee a stable 12V output regardless of what the fan is doing (off, on, spinning-up). The regulator will dissipate a similar amount of power, but they come in a package well designed to do it and you can buy off the shelf heatsinks extremely cheaply. You can get a TO-220 heatsink for [less than £1 at RS](http://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/heatsinks/2342334/).

Comment: Using LMXXX and a heatsink is about as expensive and bulky as a step-down converter, so what's the point?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev The point is it is simpler and cheaper

Comment: @ilkhd No, not really. Step-down converter costs a bit more, but will save you £1 on a heatsink.

Comment: an example of a suitable DC-DC converter would help the discussion at this point...

Answer (score 1):

Using a single resistor will not give you 12V, but something else depending on mechanical load and current rotation speed. If you use a potentiometer to determine a good value where 12V drops across the running motor, that should still work, but the spin up phase is going to take a bit longer than necessary.

The step-down converter is more efficient than a resistor or linear regulator, that is fairly obvious. Whether the heat production of the resistor is a problem depends on the actual current flowing.

A third option would be to control the current rather than the voltage, which will give you faster spin up -- you have the same options of linear regulation and switched supply there.

Answer (score 0):

Both solutions have their merits. It is therefore obviously impossible to advise you of the 'right' one without knowing more about your priorities.

However, guessing at those, I would say

a) If you are mains powered, then a resistor is so much easier than a DC-DC converter, that you should try different value resistors (starting big and working down smaller) until you find the value that gives you around 12v. Mount the resistor in the air stream from the fan if it gets too hot.

b) If you are battery powered, you probably want all the efficiency you can get. Use a DC to DC converter.